# Subwoofer problem in HP Envy

Tags: sound, 12.10, hp, speakers, ultrabook

I bought a HP ENVY 6-1060ss, it has 2 front speakers and a built-in subwoofer. I can't get the subwoofer to work. I have looked around for answers, and found quite a lot, but still, nothing works.

I have already tried (from already answered questions):

- Edited `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` setting `enable-lfe-remixing`: from `no` to `yes`, and the channels number from `2` to `3`.
- Edited `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, adding options `snd-hda-intel model=hp-zephyr` and options `snd-hda-intel model=ref`.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Just a note:  My HP dv7 also has a sub that stopped working several releases ago (it worked pre 10.04).  Interested to see an answer on this one.

Comment: You may find the answer for your problem in [this][1] thread


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/216801/5-1-surround-sound-with-three-3-5mm-jacks

Comment: Someone got an answer for this, please check (http://askubuntu.com/questions/132864/how-do-i-get-a-an-hp-envy-15-2012-edition-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me on my HP Envy w/ Beats Audio:
http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-859769.html
Ubuntu now recognizes and uses the center-channel (so-called) subwoofer.

-Todd
w.todd.land@gmail.com

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Could you clarify the exact steps you took to get this working? I've got exactly the same problem at the moment and would love to get the subwoofer working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try?

```
 sudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/extra-hdmi.conf
```

-- add the lines below:

> [Mapping analog-surround-21]
>  device-strings = surround40:%f 
>   channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe,lfe 
>  paths-output =
>   analog-output analog-output-speaker 
>  priority = 7 
>  direction = output

Reboot. You should have an extra mode in your "hardware" menu of the "sound" menu named "Analog surround 2.1"

can you do an `lspci` and tell me which sound card is your PC using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you told me, but didn't get any new hardware profiles... still, it bugs me that the ones named in the extra-hdmi.conf aren't exactly the ones shown under hardware profiles!

lspci returned:
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)

Answer (score 0):

"hdajackretask" worked for me

See http://www.smittix.co.uk/beats-audio-subwoofer-not-working-correctly-ubuntu-14-04/
and [snd-hda-intel and the HP Envy 17](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209886/snd-hda-intel-and-the-hp-envy-17)