# Alternatives to or workaround for snd-usb-audio?

Tags: sound, usb, alsa

so I have an HP envy 3040-nr ([http://www.amazon.com/HP-15-3040NR-Laptop-Black-Silver/dp/B006PCDJI2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006PCDJI2)), and after problems with usb-audio and searching around I ended having to `blacklist snd-usd-audio` in my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`.  This fixes a lot of problems with freezing, slight hangs on startup, no sound.  I recently tried un-blacklisting it and the problems returned, so that is not an option.  However, I am trying to get a midi-keyboard to work with ubuntu, and I realized that when I unblacklist snd-usb-audio it picks it up properly, but with it blacklisted the computer is unable to read it.  Does anyone have any ideas on an alternative driver I could use for usb audio? or perhaps a workaround for this very specific situation?

Any guidance appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where did you read that blacklisting snd-usb-audio helps? What is the problem with your other USB audio device? (webcam?)

Comment: I found it here http://askubuntu.com/questions/132864/how-do-i-get-a-an-hp-envy-15-2012-edition-working .  I guess it's related to pulse-audio freezing?  When I login, it causes my desktop to load really slowly, and I get some constantly pinging error message when I check the terminal on alt-f1,  I forgot what it was but perhaps later I can unblacklist and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `snd-usb-audio` driver does not have a parameter to make it ignore some specific device.

The problem with the broken wireless audio device on HP Envy laptops is known, and a [patch](http://git.kernel.org/linus/df68f106436b) exists, but this is available only in kernel version 3.8 and later.

Try to [upgrade your kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080) to 3.8.